# Bing Maps - Determine max zoom level using REST imagery API

Tags: zooming, bing-maps, bing-api

Can someone confirm to me that this can be used as an identifier for no tiles at certain zoom levels. If I issue the following request: "http://ecn.t2.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a0030300.jpeg?g=12276" in the response headers there is going to be entry "X-VE-Tile-Info=no-tile"

This can be taken as an identifier for the empty tile (image width camera)?

Also I wonder if there is a call to REST API that will use tilePositionX and tilePositionY instead lat, lon for this request: [https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Metadata/Aerial/40.714550167322159,-74.007124900817871?o=xml&zl=20&key={BINGAPI_KEY}](https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Metadata/Aerial/40.714550167322159,-74.007124900817871?o=xml&zl=20&key=%7BBINGAPI_KEY%7D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrent, that header can be used to identify if imagery is not available for that tile.

The imagery metadata service only works with latitude/longitude coordinates and not tile coordinates. The only way to check if imagery is available for a specific tile coordinate is to request the image can check the header (basically a rest service).